# How to specify a default message for posting to Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook

I am using the Facebook Javascript API to post messages to a user's wall:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

I am looking through the properties, and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the default message for a wall post. Maybe I am missing something from the page. How would I specify a default message?

Comment: are you referring to the `message` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to specify a default message is no longer available using FB.UI

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=107277

Comment: I'm not sure. Even on the docs url that you posted above, there is a "message" field in the url, and it clearly doesn't work, as the message field is blank.  You'll see it if you go down to "Direct URL Example"